# Is this function convex on the given domain?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

$$f(x_{1}, y_{1}, y_{2}, ..., y_{n}) = \dfrac{x_{1}y_{m}}{\log_{2} \left(1+\dfrac{a}{b+(\sum_{i=1}^n \ \  y_{i})-y_{m}}\right)}$$
on$\{(x_{1},y_{i})\in[0,1]\}$,and$\{a,b,m\}$ is constant,$\{m\in\{1..n\}\}$.

Is there any way to prove that it's convex or not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Inputting the expression with $n=2$ into Wolfram Alpha gives you the Hessian. My guess is that it should be easy to generalise to higher $n$

Comment: @John Thanks,I will try it.But is any way to prove it in theory?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo Thanks for your help.

Comment: What i have konwn is that $xy$ is not convex.